# How can I add pagination for my search engine?

Tags: php, search, pagination

I made a PHP search engine with multiple fields, every thing is fine and it works super but I need pagination and I want to ask, how can I create pagination for my search engine form and how can I show all record in one click.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="http://www.sayahonline.com/a/my.css">
<link href="http://www.sayahonline.com/templates/sayah/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">


</head>
<body>


<center>
<form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="idno">ID</option>
 <Option VALUE="name">Name</option>
 <Option VALUE="fname">Father Name</option>
 <Option VALUE="province">Province</option>
 </Select>
 <input placeholder="Search" type="text" name="find" /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>


<table border="1" width="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>ID</center></th>
            <th><center>Name</center></th>
            <th><center>Father Name</center></th>            
            <th><center>G/F Name</center></th>
            <th><center>School</center></th>
            <th><center>Province</center></th>
            <th><center>Grade</center></th>
            <th><center>Result</center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl">
    <p></p>
<? 
//get information
$field = @$_POST['field'] ;
$find = @$_POST['find'] ;
$searching = @$_POST['searching'] ;

 //once submitted  
 if ($searching =="yes") 
 { 
 echo "<p></p>"; 


 //blank search returns all results


 mysql_connect("localhost","User","Password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

 //filter search term 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //search database 

$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%' LIMIT $start, $per_page"); 



//display the results 
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$idno = $result ['idno'];
$name = $result ['name'];
$fname = $result ['fname'];
$gfname = $result ['gfname'];
$school = $result ['school'];
$province = $result ['province'];
$grade = $result ['grade'];
$result = $result ['result'];


echo "
        <tr>
            <td><center>$idno</center></td>
            <td>$name</td>      
            <td>$fname</td>
            <td>$gfname</td>
            <td>$school</td>
            <td>$province</td>
            <td><center>$grade</center></td>
            <td>$result</td>
        </tr>
</center> 
";

}


 //number of results or error 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($getquery); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry..."; 
 } 

 //the search term 
 echo "Result: <b>$find</b> | Total: <b>$anymatches</b> <hr size='1'>"; 
 } 




 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you like to show pagination for the different query choices?
Or would you like to show pagination for the search engine results?

Comment: I have a database with more than 300,000 rows and when I want to search someone by ID its fine but when I search by name or Father Name it shows to much rows in one page.

I would like to show pagination for the search results. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is revise your query for the search.
1) Search for the query criteria.
2) Limit the query to say, 50 or so.
3) Store the query limit in a session.
4) Create a "next 50" and "previous 50" buttons.
5) When they are clicked run the query again and use the session limit as a starting pointer in the query.
6) Go to step 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you but Iam new in PHP and I know nothing about pagination could please help me how can I do it or can I find these code from the internet?

Comment: Take a look at this web page. Read all of it and follow the instructions. You've got this far. So I'm sure you can read the web page and get it setup on your project.

Answer (score 0):

[From the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id1026131):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Just retrieve data from the database according to the current page.